# Cocos2D Project Not Working on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cocos2d-x-3.0

I just started a project in cocos studio and I want to build it for android .... but after I just opened with the emulator it just doesn't work.

This is my logcat:

> 02-14 07:43:35.805 3796-3796/org.cocos2dx.Example E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: org.cocos2dx.Example, PID: 3796
>                                                                       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2djs from loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/org.cocos2dx.Example-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.cocos2dx.Example-2,
>   /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
>                                                                           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
>                                                                           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
>                                                                           at
>   org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:248)
>                                                                           at
>   org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:263)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                           at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And this is the activity:

```
> protected void onLoadNativeLibraries() {
>         try {
>             ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(),
> PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
>             Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
>             String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");
>             System.loadLibrary(libName);
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }


// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CocosPlayClient.init(this, false);

    onLoadNativeLibraries();

    sContext = this;
    this.mHandler = new Cocos2dxHandler(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this static function to your Activity.

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("cocos2dcpp");
}
```